# How to display lookup field using <apex:inputField

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup

How can I have a lookup field

```
<apex:inputField  value="{!myobject.name}"/> //displays the name
<apex:inputField  value="{!myobject.id}"/> //displays id
```

Comment: What is the name of the lookup field in your object?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are displaying the ID/Name of the object being viewed not a reference to a different object. Allowing these to be editable via the normal lookup field UI would amount to allowing the whole object to be swapped.

If your object had a lookup field to another object (called say `Contact__c`) then this would render as a lookup field:

```
<apex:inputField  value="{!myobject.Contact__c}"/>
```

as the object referenced could be changed.

Comment: Haha self lookup...doesn't make any sense. Nice answer. +1 for *"...would amount to allowing the whole object to be swapped"*.